# AWS Cloudformation Template Deployment Failure due to SNS Topic Subscription already exists with different attributes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have AWS CloudFormation template that defines:

- A topic
- A queue
- A subscription of the queue to the SNS topic

The topic has 3 subscribers, all of them are AWS SQS queue.

Here are the excerpt of serverless.yml:

```
provider:
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'staging'}
custom:
  prefix: ${self:provider.stage}-email
  resources:
      deletionPolicy:
        local: Delete
        staging: Delete
        prod: Retain

EmailSnsTopic:
      DeletionPolicy: ${self:custom.resources.sns.deletionPolicy.${self:provider.stage}}
      Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
      Properties:
        TopicName: ${self:custom.prefix}-EmailSnsTopic
        DisplayName: "EmailSnsTopic Data ingestion pipeline"
```

The SQS Queue, and its subscription to the topic.

```
EmailQueue:
  Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
  DeletionPolicy: ${self:custom.resources.sqs.deletionPolicy.${self:provider.stage}}
  Properties:
    QueueName: ${self:custom.sqs.EmailQueueName}
    MessageRetentionPeriod: 1209600
    VisibilityTimeout: ${self:custom.sqs.MESSAGE_VISIBILITY_TIMEOUT}
    ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds: ${self:custom.sqs.RECEIVE_MESSAGE_WAIT_TIME}
    RedrivePolicy:
      deadLetterTargetArn: 
        Fn::GetAtt:
        - EmailDLQ
        - Arn
      maxReceiveCount: ${self:custom.sqs.MAX_RETRY}

EmailSnsSubscription:
      UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain
      DeletionPolicy: ${self:custom.resources.sns.deletionPolicy.${self:provider.stage}}
      Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
      Properties:
        Protocol: sqs
        Endpoint:
          Fn::GetAtt:
            - EmailQueue
            - Arn
        FilterPolicy:
          action: [{anything-but: sendSmsOnly}]
        RawMessageDelivery: false
        TopicArn: arn:aws:sns:${self:provider.region}:${self.account}:${self:provider.stage}-EmailSnsTopic
```

I have 2 environments: production and staging. The deployment at staging environment works well, without any error. But the deployment at production environment generates this error message:

> Serverless: Checking Stack update progress...
> CloudFormation - UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::CloudFormation::Stack - email-prod
> CloudFormation - CREATE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::SNS::Subscription - EmailSnsSubscription
>
> CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::SNS::Subscription - EmailSnsSubscription
> ...
> ...
> CloudFormation - UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE - AWS::CloudFormation::Stack - email-prod
> Serverless: Operation failed!
>
> Serverless Error ---------------------------------------
>
> An error occurred: EmailSnsSubscription - Invalid parameter: Attributes Reason: Subscription already exists with different attributes (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameter; Request ID: xxx-xxxx-xxxxx; Proxy: null).

I am very confused because it works at staging environment, but not at production environment.

What are possible root causes of the problem?

Comment: How do you differentiate between prod and dev environments in your template? It seems you want to create same subscription twice.

Comment: I differentiate it by this defining these values

custom:  prefix: ${self:provider.stage}-${self:service}
 

Then use it as the topic name:
TopicName: ${self:custom.prefix}-EmailSnsTopic

Comment: But do you have two `EmailQueue`? Maybe you are trying to subscribe the same queue twice?

Comment: No, The subscription uses 1 queue only. The differences between staging and environment is. deletionPolicy. .... staging: Delete,  ..prod: Retain

Comment: That's why you have an error. Your stack tries to create same queue again. Its better to have two queues, one for production and one for dev.

Comment: The queue name is different due to its ${prefix} value. The prod queue, has "prod-" prefix, and the staging queue has "staging-" prefix.

Comment: Hi @MuntasirR Did you find a solution please? I am facing the same issue and I can't delete and recreate the subscription because its on use in prod.

Comment: @ZuzuJH yes i did. 
In my case, there were some subscriptions tied to the SNS. The solution is removing those subscriptions.

Comment: Hey @ZuzuJH, I already remove all subscriptions tied to the topic. but the topic is still exists in a strange way that it was already removed.